# R caption contains "&" Misplaced Alignment tabs

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a kable table that works normally, but as the amount of tables I need per 'user' is more than a page, I need to add a caption in order for the tables to be comprehensible.  I have the following code.

```
name <- "This & That"
kable(head(mtcars),
  format = "latex",
  row.names = FALSE,
 caption = paste(as.character(sub("&", "\\&",name)), "Car Score Input")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, font_size = 10,latex_options = "HOLD_position", position = "left") %>%
 row_spec(row = 0, bold = TRUE, underline = F, background = "orange", color = "white", italic = FALSE, monospace = FALSE, strikeout = FALSE)%>% 
print(floating = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

as an example.  the name variable is *sometimes* something like "This & That" originally, I just had '`name`' in the `paste` function but I get the following error:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> ...ab:unnamed-chunk-6} This & That Car Score Input}
```

name changes and goes through a bunch of other names, some with ampersand and some without

As you can see, I've found some forums that advise for adding `\\` to the front of the character to avoid it thinking it is an escape code, but it seems no matter what I try I cannot get it to be thought of as a character.  the `as.character(sub("&", "\\&", name))` has been nested, I tried `sub` alone, before pairing it with `as.character` I'm just running out of ideas.  The kable eventually loops through a variety of names, I even tried assigning the `sub` function output to name prior to adding it to the caption, it does appear as `This \\& That` however, I get the same error in the caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\\&` with an additional pair of backslashes `\\\\&`:

```r
library(kableExtra)

name <- "This & That"

kable(head(mtcars),
      format = "latex",
      row.names = FALSE,
      caption = paste(as.character(sub("&", "\\\\&", name)), "Car Score Input")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, font_size = 10,latex_options = "HOLD_position", position = "left") %>%
  row_spec(row = 0, bold = TRUE, underline = F, background = "orange", color = "white", italic = FALSE, monospace = FALSE, strikeout = FALSE)%>% 
  print(floating = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: That works! Thanks :) adding `escape = FALSE` to the kable worked too, BUT it caused me formatting problems in the table later on that I couldn't fix,  I appreciate this

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the `escape = TRUE` argument, I suspect this applies to the body of the table rather than the caption, have to delve into `kable` function to really understand this.